# C# WPF Label and ScrollBar won't update

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this piece of code:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                                {
                                    label_pitch.Content = _pitch.ToString();
                                    scrPitch.Value = _pitch;

                                    label_yaw.Content = _yaw.ToString();
                                    scrYaw.Value = _yaw;
                                    ...
                                }));
```

Problem that I'm having is that label_pitch refreshes while label_yaw doesn't. Label_yaw gets a new value every 15 milliseconds, however even though it is provided, the label itself doesn't update.

Anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Dispatcher.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) requires delegate, just supplying signature will not help.

**Use this.**

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{ 
     label_pitch.Content = _pitch.ToString();
     scrPitch.Value = _pitch;
     label_yaw.Content = _yaw.ToString();
     scrYaw.Value = _yaw;
}));
```